# What is the US equivalent of Golden Syrup (UK)?

Tags: syrup, sweeteners

Having recently moved from UK to US, when making honeycomb, what should I use as a replacement for Golden Syrup?

Comment: I assume honey comb here isn't the larvae-protecting sheets of wax made by bees? Excuse my new world ignorance. Is it this stuff? http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/honeycomb_80005

Comment: Maple syrup in Canada ;)

Comment: @Preston Have you come across the term cinder toffee? Or a Cadbury's crunchie bar? It's that stuff. It uses hot sugar and baking powder to create that honeycomb texture.

Comment: @SamLee Nope, but it sounds great.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Honeycomb can be made with honey or molasses but the flavor will not be the same. There isn't a US equivalent - we have molasses, but it's darker. You can substitute corn syrup in recipes where it isn't the principal ingredient, but here that would not work.

That being said, my local grocery store has a British food section which carries golden syrup. You probably don't have to substitute, you just need to find it in your local grocer.

Edit: Another answer suggests "King's Golden Syrup" as a golden syrup available in the US. This is *not* golden syrup - this is corn syrup derived product containing: Corn Syrup, High Fructose Corn Syrup, Refiners Syrup, Water, Potassium Sorbate and Citric Acid.

If you look at the ingredients of Lyle's Golden Syrup to compare, it contains simply Cane Sugar Syrup.

Answer (score 8):

I use Golden Syrup, here in the US, all the time; I find it in the regular baking section, but I have seen it, like the previous answer, in the international section. I'm sure it's the same in the UK, but here it now comes in easy-pour plastic bottles (just in case you were looking for it in different packaging), rather than only in tins like I used to buy (centuries ago) at the British NAAFI in Rheindahlen, Germany. I have actually substituted it for corn syrup (my nephew is allergic to corn) w/*great* results (you must stir constantly when making peanut brittle because it burns faster, but it still makes great brittle, & it makes a *slightly* softer truffle, but not enough that most would notice), so I'd be interested to hear what happened if you still cannot find Golden Syrup in your area and *did* use corn syrup...perhaps you'd have to add some cane sugar, to keep it from being too stiff (ahem)? I'm not a food chemist, *obviously*, but I do like to experiment with food & was happily surprised by my results. My other answer would be "Amazon. They have everything."

Comment: As an addition to my note above, I also just googled "golden syrup" & found there is an American brand, "King Golden Syrup". You might find that in your local grocery, if they don't have Lyle's. I still would like to hear how your honeycomb comes out using corn syrup! If it's anything like brittle, where you heat the sugar & corn syrup very high & add baking soda at the end (baking soda foams the mix), it would work just fine. I could see calling that "honeycomb", especially if you didn't stretch it thin when poured, as we do for brittles. Very light & melt-in-your-mouth, but w/crunch as well.

Comment: I've added a note to my answer re: King's Golden Syrup. That's a corn syrup product, not a true golden syrup.

Answer (score 5):

make your own golden syrup by boiling sugar and water and add a little lemon juice to stop it crystalizing there are a few videos on youtube to show you how its made well easy hope this helps another brit now living in the usa

Comment: This sounds like a great idea but you could improve your answer by mentioning one or two in particular that you've found to work. Even better would be to include a summary of your favourite technique here to save searching elsewhere.

Comment: This is an inverted syrup (which is one of the things that seem to be sold as "golden syrup"). Recipe that works for me: cook 1:1 (by weight) sugar and water for ~1h at 80-90°C with the juice of one lemon per litre water, then boil it down to ~118°C (gives a light golden color, a thin honey like viscosity). A very versatile ingredient!

Comment: The classic Tate and Lyle golden syrup is a 'partialy' inverted syrup.  I don't know what that means, but I'm reading the tin as I type this!

Comment: This is a good guide on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijG7Yn96B-g

Answer (score 2):

I had never heard of golden syrup and found these when I googled it.

You can order it online, for example [from King Arthur](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/shop/items/lyles-golden-syrup).

And you can [make your own as in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksIHlV9T17U).

Answer (score 2):

I find it odd when people say there's no equivalent in the USA, I beg to differ . We have Golden Eagle Brand golden syrup since 1928 that's made right here by hand to this day. It's made in Fayette, Alabama and it's far superior to Lyle's. You can order it online it's $3 a pint!! You can order it in the 16 oz or all the way up. I usually purchase the 32 oz for $6. If you haven't tried it please do!! Check out their Facebook page GOLDEN EAGLE SYRUP.

Comment: Golen Eagle Syrup from Alabama may work like Lyle's golden syrup in a recipe or it may not. It isn't the same thing at all. Lyle's has no corn syrup or high fructose corn syrup nor honey.Golden Eagle has all three. The first two ingredients being potentially unsafe for those with corn allergy. The flavor would be different too, causing some people to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S.A. you can buy Lyles Golden Syrup (11.46 ounce) in the International Foods section at Publix.

Comment: For those of us in the US but not near Florida, Publix appears to be a regional supermarket chain in the Southeastern US.

Answer (score -1):

just make your own...its simple and for 1/4 price

Comment: Welcome! This sounds like a good idea, and has been suggested by some of the previous answers. Do you have a specific method or recipe that has worked well for you that you would like to share?